# "touch and feel" at custom HTML drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, mousehover

I made a custom drop down menu on a `HTML` page + `JavaScript`. I want that menu to act as following:

- When the button "Freunde" gets clicked, the drop down menu appears
- When the button gets clicked again, the drop down menu disappears
- When the mouse curor leaves the "area" of button + drop down menu, it disappears

The drop down menu consists of a main div with multiple divs in it (the "menu items").

My first approach was to put a `onmouseout()` on the main div of the drop down menu, but there is following problem: As soon as I hover over an inner div, the `onmouseout()` is true, and since the inner divs fill the entire main div, the drop down menu is visible only as long as the user doesn't hover over it.

So I tried it to solve similiarly like a JQuery lightbox, namely to put a "background" div over the whole screen and paste the drop down menu in there, and set the `onmouseover()` there. That would be almost perfect, but the "Freunde" button is also affected from that.

So is there any way to combine an event from different elements? Like

```
if(cursor is not over Button && cursor is not over DDMenu)  set invisible
```

I marked the desired are in following image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're set up as

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

You could set up your CSS like this:

```
#nav ul li ul { display: none; }
#nav ul li.active:hover ul { display: block; }
```

And then set up your JS like this:

```
var menuClick = function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    menuHover();
};
var menuHover = function() {
    $('#nav li.active').hover(function() {

    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});

$('#nav > ul > li').on('click', menuClick);
```

Granted, this is absolutely gross coding, but I think it should work. (this also assumes you're using the jQuery library).